# Naming convention for allocated/non-allocated strings

Tags: c, string, naming-conventions, memory-management

Are there any common naming conventions to differentiate between strings that are allocated and not allocated? What I am looking for is hopefully something similar to `us`/`s` from 
[Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html), but I'd rather use something common than make up my own.

Comment: This should probably be over on programmers.stackexchange.com, not stackoverflow.

Comment: Boy oh boy, Stackoverflow is getting really picky when selection of a variable name is no longer a programming activity.

Comment: This belongs on SO, not programmers, especially since it's language-specific (C).

Answer (score 1):

The us / s convention in the article is somewhat useful, but it misses a greater point.  The point is that variable naming conventions are only as good at protecting from missteps as documentation.

For example:

```
#Version 1

char* sHello = "Hello";
printf("%s\n", sHello);
```

which gets modified eventually to

```
#Version 2
char* sHello = "Hello";
... 100 lines of code ...
sHello = realloc(sHello, strlen(sHello)+7);
strcpy(sHello+strlen(sHello), " World");
... 100 lines of code ...
printf("%s\n", sHello);
```

When you really want to make a coding convention work, you can't rely on some sort of arbitrary (and yes, they are all arbitrary) naming conventions.  You have to back up that naming convention with a means of failing the build.  In the above case, judicious use of the keyword `const` would have done the trick, but the coding convention will lull people into complacency that it's right because it's named a certain way.

It's the documentation problem all over again, eventually in-code documentation gets out-of-sync with the code, and your in-code naming convention will eventually get out-of-sync with the usage of those names.

Now, if you want to add typing information to C (which is really what you're getting at), do it via a system that actually adds types to c, `typedef`.  Then put in place a system that can verify if the type is not being used when it is required and fail the build.  Anything else will cost you too much after-the-fact searching / maintenance / cleanup, and half of an implemented coding style is just so much worse than even a bad coding style.

Comment: Contrary to its name, `typedef` does *not* define a new type - it defines an *alias* for an existing type.  The keyword for defining a new type in C is actually `struct` - if you have `struct foo { int n; } a;` and `struct bar { int n; } b;` then the compiler will not let you assign `a = b;`.

Comment: Good points. I will try out with "struct astr { char *s; }; /* allocated string */" or something similar after summer vacation.